# How is this Java program executed?

Tags: java

```
    class Welcome{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            System.out.println(Hello.a);
        }
    }
    class Hello{
        static int a=10;
        static Hello h=new Hello();
        {
            System.out.println("IB");
        }
        static{
            System.out.println("SB");
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
 IB
 SB
 10
```

I really don't understand the logic behind this execution. According to me, the static variables are initialized and static block gets executed. Then, the instance variable is initialized and instance block is executed.

However, this seems to be a bit confusing. It would be a great help if a step-by-step order of actual execution is given.

What is the meaning of `static Hello h=new Hello();`?

How will this be treated?

Comment: In what way(s) does your description not fit the output?

Comment: Please follow the way of  object oriented programming where in you need to Encapsulate each data fields as private members of a class..

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the `class` keyword and ran it through. The execution is quite straight forward when you see it running.

1. Static variables are initialised. That means `a` and `h` are set.
2. Initialiser blocks are ran. So "IB" is printed. They run because the value of `h` is a new `Hello` object.
   **NOTE**: This only happens because `h` is defined before the `static` initializer block in the class. If you change the order they appear in the code, then the order of execution will change.
3. Static initialiser blocks are ran. So "SB" is printed.
4. main method is invoked, which prints out `Hello.a`. So `10` is printed.

**IDEOne Link**: http://ideone.com/KfdS6n

Comment: Only partly correct. The instance initializer is run *specifically* because the `new Hello()` appears before the static initializer *in text order*. Reorder the `new Hello()` to after the static block, and it should change.

Comment: I realised that I had omitted this from my explanation just before I saw your comment. My answer has been amended. Edit: Made it a little bit more clear based on your feedback.